# Ancova Levene's test significant

Tags: ancova

I did ANCOVA with Depended: Posttest/ Fixed: Group/ Covariate: pretest
Levene's test is statistically significant: .002
Is the assumption of homogeneity of variance violated? If yes , what can i do about it?

I am asking since I had done it with Univariate analysis: Postest, Group. pretest and custom model with interaction between group and pretest and interaction Grupa*test1 was not significant.

Answer (score 3):

1) The assumption of equality of variance is *almost never exactly satisfied*

2) ANOVA isn't very sensitive to mild differences in variance, so your ability to reject the null in the Levene test may be almost irrelevant in large samples; correspondingly an inability to reject the null in small samples should be *no comfort whatever*. Hypothesis tests are simply answering the wrong question [The question: "do the variances differ?" ... to which the correct answer is almost always 'yes, they do' ... is almost useless, since we know the answer already, and a hypothesis test only tells us what we already know in sufficiently large samples. A much better question is *How much does that affect my inference?* -- which is not answered by a hypothesis test; it's more related to the relative sizes of the variances, and to the relative sizes of the samples they occur in].

3) If sample sizes are equal (or very nearly so), then the ANOVA isn't sensitive to the assumption.

---

A better choice than testing variance and then choosing what analysis to apply based on the outcome of that test is to not assume equal variances at all (unless you have a reason to do so). A Welch-Satterthwaite type approach works pretty well - just use it whenever you don't have a good reason to do otherwise.